# How to invest in the Russian oil market?

Tags: stocks, investing, russia

I didn't find a brokerage that offers access to the Russian stock market. The are few Russian ETFs, but they are broad.

Has anyone experience in investing in Russia stock market? If so, how?

Comment: +0.  If you want to invest in oil, you could invest in your country's oil market.  If you want to invest in Russia, you could invest in a broad-based Russian ETF.  Why would you want to invest specifically in the Russian oil market?

Comment: Are you asking about the oil market or about the stock market?

Answer (score 4):

The Russian ETFs may be broad, but a quick glance at ERUS and RBL's sector breakdown shows they're 45% and 47% energy sector, and their top holding is Gazprom comprising 9% and 14% of each ETF respectively, with plenty more oil and gas companies in their top 10 too.  A harder question would be how to invest in Russia and *avoid* oil I think (and even then, the economy is thoroughly bound up in it).

To rework a [meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_reversal)... ***In Soviet Russia, oil invest YOU!***